# Is it ethical to submit a paper to journal then to Research Square? And what is the difference between that research square and ArXiv?

Tags: journals, arxiv

I sent yesterday a paper to a journal of publisher Springer for consideration, in the same time I have got a new  free distribution service and an open-access called [Research Square](https://www.researchsquare.com/). It looks like Arxiv; it is not peer-reviewed  and makes research available in a fast way. Now  I want to know: should I withdraw my paper from that research square service since I sent it to a journal for review, or should I leave it there for comments to improve my paper in the future? Is what I did ethical? More than that, I want to know the difference between that Research Square and [Arxiv](https://arxiv.org/).

Comment: Why not just post to the arXiv? The arXiv is far and away the preprint sharing service most commonly used in mathematics...

Comment: Just clicking on the link, it seems "research square" is mainly a place for medical preprints - I doubt that a significant part of the mathematics community will see it there. Not sure to what extent it is connected to the commercial publishers. I second the recommendation by @SamHopkins to just submit to arXiv. As to the main ethics question, this is simply a matter of what kind of copyright agreement you have signed or will have to sign with the journal - apart from that, you should be able to disseminate as you please (perhaps your employer has something to say about it as well).

Comment: Springer seems to be one of the sponsors of Research Square, so I doubt Springer itself would object.

Comment: Research Square seems to be a business. I do not think you have any way to assess the implications arising from using it that will arrive in a year. So why deal with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want to know the difference between that Research Square and Arxiv.

One of the differences is that Arxiv is a not-for-profit service and is not actively trying to sell you stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Experience shows that it is OK to post a paper on the arXiv, before or after it is published or submitted, provided that you use your own TeX file, not the file edited/formatted by the journal.
And I do not see any reason whatsoever for posting a math paper on any other preprint server, since most mathematicians post on the arXiv.

Comment: Ermenko , I have posted it there because the topic is related to such application in medecine

Comment: Arxiv is the place where most mathematicians post their mathematical papers, so this is the place where they are most likely to look. Of course, if the paper is interdisciplinary, there may be other archives appropriate for posting it. I cannot compare them, since I am not familiar with this other archive. My experience is limited to mathematics.